# Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.keyvault.secrets' although I installed the package

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-keyvault

I have a Python script to retrieve username and password from Key Vault (Azure). 3 months ago it worked but now it gives me the error `No module named 'azure.keyvault.secrets'` when I run `'from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient'`.
Why I get this error?

It gives me error also if I try to run `pip install azure`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.keyvault.secrets' although I installed the package:

If you run `pip install azure` it won't work for `azure.keyvaults` module to be used in the code. You need to install or update with the latest version using `pip` command:

```py
pip install azure-keyvault-secrets //4.6.0 is the latest one.
```

***Installed successfully:***

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem didn't solve. I think that the problem is on my Python environment. I will let you know! Thank you anyway!

Comment: Did you upgarde `pip` version?

Comment: Yes, also setuptools but didn't change.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.9 version

Comment: For me, 3.9 was working. Can you update the python version to 3.11 or 3.10 and try?

Comment: I updated it to 3.10 and now it works! Thank you!